# object relational schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following types, tables, and data. How can I write an Oracle statement to get the `sid` and `sname` of only students with a `deptid` of 5?

```
create type St_t as object
(
  sid char(4),
  sname varchar(20)
) NOT FINAL;
/

create type St_t as object
(
  sid char(4),
  sname varchar(20)
) NOT FINAL;
/

create type ugt_t under St_t
(
  gpa real,
  deptid integer
)
/

create table Stud of St_t;
create table ug of ugt_t;

insert into Stud values(ugt_t('s001','harry',3.5,5));
insert into Stud values(ugt_t('s002','jhon',2.7,6));
```

I tried this, but didn't get the expected output

```
SELECT sname, TREAT(VALUE(p) AS ugt_t).deptid =5 
FROM person p 
WHERE VALUE(p) IS OF (ONLY ugt_t);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you expected the output to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following example may help you to find a solution (works with Oracle 12c):

**types** (same as in your question)

```
create type St_t as object
(
  sid char(4),
  sname varchar(20)
) NOT FINAL;
/

create type ugt_t under St_t
(
  gpa real,
  deptid integer
)
/
```

**tables**

```
create table students ( student st_t ) ;
create table undergraduates ( undergrad ugt_t ) ;
```

**inserts**

```
-- fails
begin
  insert into undergraduates values( 's001', 'harry', 4.5, 5  );
  insert into undergraduates values( 's002', 'john', 3.7, 6  );
end ;
/

ORA-06550: line 2, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
-- ... etc

-- works
begin
  insert into undergraduates values( ugt_t( 's001', 'harry', 4.5, 5 )  );
  insert into undergraduates values( ugt_t( 's002', 'john', 3.7, 6 )  );
end ;
/
```

**queries**

```
SQL> select * from undergraduates;
UNDERGRAD                   
oracle.sql.STRUCT@7d900ecf  
oracle.sql.STRUCT@6f01b95f               


-- answer to your question
select 
  U.undergrad.sid
, U.undergrad.sname
from undergraduates U 
where U.undergrad.deptid = 5 ;

UNDERGRAD.SID  UNDERGRAD.SNAME  
s001           harry
```